# uniform histograms in copula approach

Tags: r, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, copula

I would like to model some time series. For this purpose I have the marginal distribution and want to use a gaussian copula to build the dependency. Following a tutorial the following should give me the desired dependency structure with correct marginals

```
library(mvtnorm)
S <- matrix(c(0.025,0.0075,0.0075,0.007),2,2)
normal <- rmvnorm(n = 1000,mean = c(4.1,2.08),sigma = S)
uniform <- pnorm(normal)
hist(uniform[,1])
hist(uniform[,2])
```

However, the histograms look not at all like a uniform distribution. What is wrong with the above code?
The help of "rmvnorm" says sigma is the covariance matrix. Looking at other example in the web I see that often they use the correlation matrix. So what is expected by rmvnorm?
Moreover, the covariance of uniform should stay the same. However, I get the following result:

```
cov(uniform)
             [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 3.481586e-10 3.626536e-08
[2,] 3.626536e-08 1.440411e-05
>
```

which varies a lot from the input matrix $S$. So whats going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the link for the tutorial or anywhere that shows that the result should be a uniform distribution? As it stands, this looks like a coding question and thus not appropriate for CV.

Comment: The code is from this blog http://www.r-bloggers.com/copulas-made-easy/ if its not appropriate for CV feel free to move it to overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the usage of `pnorm`. `pnorm` is used to calculate the CDF (or by default, 1- CDF) $F(q)$ for a standard normal. That is `pnorm(q)` is going to calculate

$$u = P(X \geq q) $$

for when $X \sim N(0,1)$. However, in your example, your normal distributions are not mean 0 and variance 1. So you need to adjust your pnorms, like

```
uniform <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 2)
S <- matrix(c(0.025,0.0075,0.0075,0.007),2,2)
normal <- rmvnorm(n = 1000, mean = c(4.1,2.08),sigma = S)
uniform[,1] <- pnorm(normal[,1], mean = 4.1, sd = sqrt(.025))
uniform[,2] <- pnorm(normal[,2], mean = 2.08, sd = sqrt(.007))
hist(uniform[,1])
hist(uniform[,2])
```

[image]

The r-bloggers code worked because they used mean 0 and unit variance in their `rmvnorm`. It has nothing to do with correlation matrix.

Comment: One small question regarding your answer. Shouldnt we take $1-CDF$, i.e. $1-pnorm$ given your comment at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, ideally we should, but it doesn't matter because 1-U(0,1) is also a U(0,1)